# C# webdriver tables

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Hello im fairly new to selenium and am having some difficulty working with dynamic data tables that I was hoping someone would be able to help me with.

I am trying to firstly identify the row number based on a cell value then verify all values for the row.

```html
<div id="enquiry-header-grid-SalesTransactionEnquiry-enquiry-header-grid-wrapper" class="enquiry-kendo-grid-wrapper k-grid k-widget" data-role="grid" style="height: 456px;">
<div class="k-grid-content k-auto-scrollable" style="height: 428px;">
<table role="grid" tabindex="0" data-role="selectable" class="k-selectable" style="touch-action: none;">
<colgroup><col style="width:120px"><col style="width:120px"><col style="width:100px"><col style="width:60px"><col style="width:100px"><col style="width:105px"><col style="width:100px"><col style="width:120px"><col style="width:120px"><col style="width:100px"><col style="width:200px"><col style="width:120px"><col style="width:120px"><col style="width:60px"><col style="width:100px"><col style="width:100px"><col style="width:100px"><col style="width:100px"><col style="width:100px"><col style="width:120px"><col style="width:60px"><col style="width:100px"><col style="width:100px"></colgroup>
<tbody role="rowgroup">
<tr data-uid="23f8ebd0-2c90-4728-9430-71376f2d10e3" role="row" class="k-state-selected" aria-selected="true">
<td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell"><a href="#" class="cell-popover" data-col-type="popover" data-col-name="ST_COPYCUST">MUFC</a></td>
<td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell">Manchester United</td>
<td class="col-align-right" role="gridcell">23/10/2017</td>
<td class="col-align-right" role="gridcell">1</td>
<td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell">Invoice</td>
<td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell">1000</td>
<td class="col-align-center" role="gridcell"><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"></td>
<td class="col-align-right" role="gridcell">5.00</td>
<td class="col-align-right" role="gridcell">1.00</td>
<td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell">SA</td>
<td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell"></td>
<td class="col-align-right" role="gridcell">6.00</td>
<td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell">0.00</td>
<td class="col-align-center" role="gridcell"><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"></td>
<td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell">2017</td>
<td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell">1</td>
<td class="col-align-right" role="gridcell">23/10/2017</td>
<td class="col-align-right" role="gridcell">23/10/2017</td>
<td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell"></td>
<td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell">0.00</td>
<td class="col-align-center" role="gridcell"><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"></td>
<td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell"></td></tr>
<tr class="k-alt" data-uid="5a1d2279-5588-4c41-ab22-ce5361192a4c" role="row">
```

So in the code above im trying to identify the row number based on a unique value in the off '1000' in the Header Ref column, then identify all the values for the row.

I have got as far as identifying the table and iterating through rows but cant seem to get any further,

```
            IWebElement elemTable = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='enquiry-header-grid-SalesTransactionEnquiry-enquiry-header-grid-wrapper']//table[1]"));
            List<IWebElement> lstTrElem = new List<IWebElement>(elemTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));
            foreach (var elemTr in lstTrElem)
            { 
                List<IWebElement> lstTdElem = new List<IWebElement>(elemTr.FindElements(By.TagName("td")));
                foreach (var elemTd in lstTdElem)
                {
                    IWebElement customer = elemTable.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td[contains(text(), '1000')]"));
```

any help or advice with this would be greatly appreciated!!

Update
With some help from @DebenjenB i have located the td element that contains 1000 which is great, what i now would like to do is verify that within the same tr the following td exists

```
<td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell">Manchester United</td>
```

Thanks in advance, the assistance is really helpful :)

Comment: http://sscce.org/ or https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Sorry still new to the site - i have now removed the screen shot and added the HTML

Comment: Within your inner foreach loop, could you not do something like if(elemTd.Text == "1000"){ // Do processing here }? Sorry if the .Text property is not exactly correct, I'm doing this from memory!

Answer (score 0):

To identify the *WebElement* with text as **1000** you can use the following code block :

```
List<IWebElement> lstTdElem = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='enquiry-header-grid-SalesTransactionEnquiry-enquiry-header-grid-wrapper']//table//tbody[@role='rowgroup']/tr[@class='k-state-selected']//td"));
foreach (var elemTd in lstTdElem)
{ 
    if(elemTd.GetAttribute("innerHTML") == "1000")
    {
        //do anything with the element
    }
}
```

---

### Update

Based on your updated criteria to look out for both the text **1000** and **Manchester United** within the `<tr>` you can use the following code block :

```
if(driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='enquiry-header-grid-SalesTransactionEnquiry-enquiry-header-grid-wrapper']//table//tbody[@role='rowgroup']/tr[@class='k-state-selected']//td[contains(.,'1000') or contains(.,'Manchester United')]"))>1)
    Console.WriteLine("1000 and Manchester United both exists");
else 
    Console.WriteLine("1000 and Manchester United both doesn't exists");
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding so apologies if that is the case but i am would like to get the rowid for the row which contains text "1000" and then verify the data in all columns for that row - your code above may identify the cell element which contains 1000 but how do i then get the rowid to use in verifying the date in other columns for the row?

Comment: Which attribute from the shared _HTML_ identifies a `rowid`? Can you share an example?

Comment: Again apologies maybe im not being clear - the td that in the example above has the value of 1000 is a column which will have a unique value for each row - so once i have identified this how do i then validate the values for all td's in the row??

Comment: For the `td that in the example above has the value of 1000`, which `values for all td's in the row` do you want to validate? Validate against what?

Comment: So once identified the row with value 1000 in,

Comment: <td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell">1000</td>

Comment: i then need to validate that the other td's in the row have the correct values which i know so essentially where row contains <td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell">1000</td> check that the following exist for the same row

Comment: <td class="col-align-left" role="gridcell">Manchester United</td>

Comment: <td class="col-align-right" role="gridcell">23/10/2017</td>

Comment: @Luke Cool down. Think for a while what are trying to _Automate_. Now we have found out the _WebElement_ which contains **1000**. Can you update the question with what do you want to do next?

Comment: as where the row contains td text 1000 i know what values should be in the same row - hopefully that makes a bit more sense?

Comment: Thank you very much @DebanjenB - will update the question now!

Comment: again thanks for the help - when attempting to use the above answer i am, getting the following error - operator > connot be applied to operands of type 'ReadOnlyCollection'<IWebElement' and Int